# Is it possible to change a USB's enumerated descriptors (from the OS side) after plugging it in?

Tags: arduino, usb, linux, usb-device

I don't mean as in change the descriptors built into the device, but the descriptors that the OS has enumerated. Can this be done from the OS side without touching the USB device?

For example, can I plug in a default Arduino UNO scripted to send keyboard keystroke signals, then in the OS side of things (Linux in my specific case, but I'd like to know about Windows and OS X too) change the descriptors so that the OS can interpret the device as (for example) a keyboard without ever having to modify the DFU firmware of the Arduino directly?

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to do this. It would break the whole plug-and-play ease of use scenario that's built into USB. If you have an Arduino "scripted to send keystrokes", why wouldn't you want it to identify itself as such right up front?

Comment: @DaveTweed Because i have to physically switch between Arduino mode and keyboard mode by shorting the arduino dfu pins and flashing the arduino firmware and keyboard firmware back and forth woth dfu-programmer, over and over, just to test changes. Doing it on the OS side would be easier and scriptable for testing purposes. Ultimately i'd ship the device with the actual keyboard firmware, but i'm not at that point yet.

Comment: Ardiuno is a great platform for quick-and-dirty embedded projects, but there are many projects for which it is simply not appropriate, and it sounds like yours is one of them. If you're serious about developing a real product, it's time to invest in a proper AVR in-system programmer and software development/debug environment.

Comment: ^ http://www.avrfreaks.net to get you started

Answer (score 1):

Cypress semiconductor has a line of products that do this. They call it "re-numeration". I'm not sure how feasible this is with other devices, but here is an article explaining the process that might help: http://www.cypress.com/?id=4&rID=26981

Answer (score 0):

You could modify or merge the 16u2 firmware of the UNO between the Arduino-COMBINED-dfu-usbserial-atmega16u2-Uno-Rev3 build and the HID build. So that it starts as usbserial for the same period of time that 328p's bootloader is expecting avrdude and then after that times out run the HID portion of the firmware.

Note the source for the 16u2 is .\hardware\arduino\avr\firmwares\atmegaxxu2.
and actually requires at least avr-gcc 4.3.3 (not supplied 4.3.2)
Care would need to be taken to properly shutdown the USB and restart it between descriptors.

Comment: Noting that ISCP programmers are $2-$20, I would recommend similarly the as Dave Tweed and get a programmer.

Comment: That seems like a good idea, but a little complicated for me right now. Up until now I've been a software app developer. This is my first time ever experimenting with hardware (and it happens to be with the Arduino UNO R3 that happened to be laying around here :).